# Converting cassandra result set of type SortedSet in python to Json string set

Tags: python, cassandra

I am fetching Cassandra's result set using python and one of the columns is of type Set and is getting results as:

> SortedSet([u'APPROVAL'])

> SortedSet([media_directory_summary(directory_id=UUID('4d0cf274-cfdd-47b8-a81d-a2f7017f8173'),
> name=u'test directory', url=None, imported=False,
> owner_id=UUID('63c2849f-db90-46f0-98e2-3d2764b5c1c6')),
> media_directory_summary(directory_id=UUID('8da294a3-d989-484f-801f-0f47c6dcc926'),
> name=u'Newone', url=None, imported=False,
> owner_id=UUID('63c2849f-db90-46f0-98e2-3d2764b5c1c6'))])

and my desired output is to get it in the form:

> {'APPROVAL'}

> {{directory_id: 4d0cf274-cfdd-47b8-a81d-a2f7017f8173, name: 'test
> directory', url: null, imported: False, owner_id:
> 63c2849f-db90-46f0-98e2-3d2764b5c1c6}, {directory_id:
> 8da294a3-d989-484f-801f-0f47c6dcc926, name: 'Newone', url: null,
> imported: False, owner_id: 63c2849f-db90-46f0-98e2-3d2764b5c1c6}}

I tried converting it this way but not working as needed.

```
for row in self.session.execute(query):
    for val in row:
        if isinstance(val, cassandra.util.SortedSet):
           for Sorted in val:
               self.log.info(Sorted)
               for media_summary in Sorted:
                   self.log.info(media_summary)
```

With this, I am unable to get the desired results.
Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

The `SortedSet` implements the `iterable` interface, so you can just pass it to the `set` function, and get the "normal set" that you can use:

```
>>> from cassandra.util import *
>>> a = SortedSet([1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 5])
>>> a
SortedSet([1, 3, 4, 5])
>>> set(a)
{1, 3, 4, 5}
```

Comment: Using the code as:
```for val in row:
         if isinstance(val, SortedSet):
              self.log.info(val)
              self.log.info(set(val))
```
# output
SortedSet([u'APPROVAL'])
set([u'APPROVAL'])

I need in the form: {'APPROVAL'}. It isn't working